# Pure CSS Sub Dropdown Menu

Tags: css

I am trying to create a menu that has 3 sub menus and I have successfully created the first 2.  My issue is with the 3rd drop-down menu,  It is only showing one `<li>` when there is multiple available.

**CSS**

```
   /*Reset */
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, form, input, ul, ol, p, fieldset, header, footer, section, aside, nav, article, figure  { display:block; padding: 0; margin: 0; }

/* Main CSS */
html, body,#wrapper{

    width:990px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrapper{
    position: absolute;
}
#header{
    position:relative z-index:500;
    background:url('../images/header.png');
    width:990px;
    height:220px;
}

/*Menu */
nav{
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    margin:0px 0 0 40px;
}

nav ul{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:14px;
    width:190px;
}

nav ul li{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li ul{
    display:none;
}

nav ul li ul li ul li{
    display:none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    left:190px;
    top:0px;
}

nav ul li ul li:hover li{ /* edit page drop down */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}


nav li a{
    font-size:14px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:25px; /*Text Hight On Button */
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:25px;
    display:block;
    margin-left:-40px;
    width:190px;
    height:27px;
    background-image:url('../images/normal.png');
}

nav a:hover{
    background-image:url('../images/onclick.png');
}

/*Content */

#content{
    margin: 0 0 0 190px;
    width:815px;
    height:95%;
}

#content h1{
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', arial, serif;
    font-size:24px;
}

#content p{
    margin:0 0 0 15px;
}

#content li{
    margin:0 0 0 35px;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

footer{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;;
    bottom:0;
    background:url('../images/footer.png') no-repeat #000;
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
}

#leftCol{
    float:left;
    width:190px;
    height:100%;
    background:url('../images/metalnavbg.png');
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

/* Misc*/
/* Text Formatting */

#companyName{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:45px;
    font-size:35px;
    color:#f0f0ef;
}

#companyQuote{
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#a5a4a2;
}

/*Forms */

/*General*/

#validation{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ff0101;
}
.contactForm{
    width: 450px;
    height:425px;
    padding: 35px 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#validation{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ff0101;
}

.form{
    width: 400px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.borderradius.form{
    width: 400px;
    height:100%;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

fieldset{
    border:none;
}

#formLayout{
    border:2px solid #000;
}

#formLayout label{
   clear:  both;
    display: block;
}

#formLayout input{
    font-size:12px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    padding: 6px 8px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    color: #000;
    width: 250px;
}



#formLayout .small{
    color:#ff0101;
    display:block;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    width:140px;
}

#formLayout textarea{
    width:250px;
}

#error{

    width:250px;
    height:20px;
    margin:-30px 0 0 270px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#error p{
    color:#ff0101;
    text-align:left;
}

/* Specific Form Class's */

.login{
    width: 470px;
    height:250px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.login label{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.login .loginSubmit{
        margin-top:25px;
}
/*Gallery CSS */


#gallery{
    width:120px;
    margin-left:5px;
    display: inline;
}

#gallery .thumbnail{
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline;
} 

#gallery img{
    margin:5px;
}

#sales{
    width:190px;
    height:195px;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


#sales .location{
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:15px;
}

#sales .price{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:5px;
    color:#ff0101;
}

#deleteImage{
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

#deleteImage .thumbnail{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:90px;
    width:90px;
}
```

Comment: Too much CSS and where is the HTML? Just to make sure it isn't an HTML error.

Comment: Your issue isn't that only one `<li>` is showing, it's that they are all stacked on top of each other(or at least the are with my run of it). Try giving the `<li>` items different text values. I'll try to find the cause.

Comment: I agree with robx on this one. Next time rather than posting all of your CSS, just post what you think would be relevant to the question. This would probably include any HTML that is involved in the question as well. It will make it a lot easier for us to sift through the information and get an answer to you quicker ;)

Comment: mock it up in http://cssizer.com and id be glad to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nav ul li ul li:hover li{
    display:block;
    position:absolute; /* <--- it's right here */
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Found the issue. You are setting your 3rd set of `<li>` items to absolute and then forcing them into the top-left corner of your enclosing `<ul>` for that list. You're probably looking for something like this:

```
nav ul li ul li:hover ul{/* reference the ul instead of the contained <li>s */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
```

Comment: I get the following ->  http://cl.ly/3U3C1H0s3U182o1t2S1r on hover http://cl.ly/3B3k0o0i0s0n1t423G2E